# Algorithm suggestions for distinguishing images of human faces

Tags: image-processing, opencv, image-recognition

I am looking to develop a facial algorithm that would take as input 2 images and calculates if the faces in the 2 images are of the same person or not. I have all the pre-processing of the images working using OpenCV. In the prepossessing steps I crop the face from the entire image, convert it to gray-scale, and resize it to a standard size. My problem is a bit different from facial recognition in the sense that I am not concerned with identifying the individual in the image, I just want to be able to say if they are the same person or not. Most facial recognition algorithms I looked at rely on training from sample faces of the same persons that will comprise the input. In my situation I can train with general faces but not exact faces that will be in the input.  Could you please suggest some methods that could work in my situation?

Comment: detection of a pair of same faces and face classification are simply two operational modes of face recognition. Most face recognition algorithms can be adapted to operate in both modes (giving different performances); therefore, the algorithms you found will still be useful to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem, perceptual hashing along with edit distance might be more proper.

Check out

- http://phash.org/
- [Looks Like It](http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/432-Looks-Like-It.html)
- [TinEye Reverse Image Search](http://www.tineye.com/)

Comment: TinEye does a good job indexing images on the web. I think what we have here is quite different. I tested that with a reasonable image that doesn't come straight off the web. I took a screenshot of John Lennon's face from this interview on YouTube (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iREKEWdjAUU) and TinEye found no matches, honestly declaring: "TinEye looks for the specific image you uploaded, not the content of the image. TinEye does not identify people or objects in an image." See for yourself, the query is cached upto 72 hrs http://www.tineye.com/search/a4981f401b2596a641f3e514103724b5bff3b9fd/

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would measure distances between features.

If you can't control the position/size/angle of the image - ie it's a real world image, not someone sitting in front of a face scanner - then you need to think about how to make these all ratios.

Try finding the eyes (easy) and the mouth or nose and get the sides/angle of the triangle.
You can then also do percentage of face area covered by hair, width/length ratio of nose etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Face recognition from a single image per person: A survey](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.125.6725&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, look into Wavelet methods.  See [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel4%2F5501%2F14786%2F00670944.pdf%3Farnumber%3D670944&authDecision=-203) for example.